# problema al actualizar app en google play

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

Buenos días, tengo una aplicación que había subido al google  play, pero recientemente le hice cambios y mejoras, y luego, lo subí al play store. todo eso cambiando el gradle y la versión code correctamente. Sin embargo, cuando veo el aplicativo en play store, en un celular que ya había instalado una versión anterior, no sale "actualizar" solo "instalar" (aunque sale la nueva versión que le puse). ¿qué estaría mal?

--graddle--

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {  
    compileSdkVersion 23  
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"  
    defaultConfig {  
        applicationId '************'  
        minSdkVersion 19  
        targetSdkVersion 23  
        versionCode 3  
        versionName "2"  
    }  
    buildTypes {  
        release {  
            minifyEnabled false  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'  
            debuggable false  
            renderscriptDebuggable false  
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3  
            zipAlignEnabled true  
            jniDebuggable false  
        }  
        debug {  
            debuggable true  
        }  
    }  
    productFlavors {  
        Newapp {  
        }  
    }  
}  

dependencies {  
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')  
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'  
    compile      'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'  
    compile files('D:/AndroidStudio/Newapp/libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'  
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0'  
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'  
}
```

Comment: Si quieres agregar código debes de pegarlo como texto no como imagen.

Comment: ya está. solo es el graddle

Comment: que pasos usaste para subirla de nuevo a Google play?

Comment: lo subi como nuevo apk en producción donde estaba el apk anterior. en el historial de versiones se ven el número de versiones y el nombre de la  versión

Comment: Revisa si tienen el mismo nombre de paquete...

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente borra el cache de la aplicación Google PlayStore.

Si eso no lo resuelve entonces,si subiste previamente una aplicación a la tienda `Google PlayStore` y al subir una nueva versión obtienes un mensaje de instalar el problema debe ser el paquete de la aplicación, si fue cambiado indica que es otra aplicación, revisa este valor en el `build.gradle` o en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

Recuerda también que el `versionCode` debe ser consecutivo a la versión anterior.

```
android {  
    ...
    ... 
    defaultConfig {  
        ...
        ...
        versionCode 4  
        versionName "4"  
    }
}
```